# Why is my C program not giving correct output?

Tags: c

Here is my C program that converts binary into decimal. But it is not working I don't know why?
Please help me solve this issue.
Help me to find errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>



int main(){
char bin[1000];
int dec=0;
int k=1;

printf("Enter bin : ");
scanf("%s",bin );

int length=0;
while(bin[length]!='\0'){
    length++;
}


for(int i=length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--){
    dec=dec+bin[i]*k ;
    k=k*2 ;
}
printf("%d",dec);




getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is clearly homework of some kind, not replying with code, but with a hint: What do you think the value of `bin[i]` is in your loop? You might want to check those values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is very helpful when asking for help to describe what you observe.

For example what you expected to see and what the output of the program actually is

Comment: Try to think about the types of each variable. What would be the result of an addition between variables of different types? How is a `char` represented?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to convert entered ASCII '0' and '1' to integer 0 and 1, as '1' is in fact 49 and '0' is 48 (see ASCII table):

```
dec=dec+(bin[i]-'0')*k ;
```

Comment: Why do you think the character codes use ASCII? Literally, what makes you think that? Did you read in some book that character codes are ASCII? Did somebody tell you? What do you think about the possibility that some other code system might be used—is that allowed or not allowed?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because people around me usually use ASCII in console C programs. Besides that, have you noticed the "probably" word in my answer?

Comment: “Probably” modifies “need to convert,” not “ASCII” or “'1' is in fact 49.” I phrased these as questions to get you to think about how and why you know certain things. One reason bugs occur in programs is because authors make assumptions. Sometimes assumptions are correct, and sometimes they are incorrect. So it is important to know where your information comes from and whether it applies in a particular situation. That is important to teach students; they should not be taught assumptions as “fact,” such as which character code system is used.